# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. in .NET 8

Tags: .net, sql-server, migration, relation

This is my connection string :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"EvSefDBConnection": "Server=.;Database=evsef_db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

and this is my database setting:

```
builder
    .Services
    .AddDbContext<EvSefDbContext>(options => {
        options
            .UseSqlServer(
                builder
                    .Configuration
                    .GetConnectionString("EvSefDBConnection"));});
```

but after Add- migration , when I want to update , I see this error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: Check the value of `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("EvSefDBConnection")`, does it match your connection string here?

Comment: Make sure that correct settings file is used.  Which configuration file contains the specified connection string? Is it some environment-specific one (like `appsettings.Development.json`)?

Comment: `Server=.` <= is that valid?

Comment: @DavidG yes it is

Comment: @DaleK yes , I add TrustServerCertificate=True; it works

Comment: @GuruStron I have this code in my context ,

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("EvSefDBConnection");
        }   
I delete it and edit connection string to :TrustServerCertificate=True; and it work

Answer (score 0):

I delete this code from context:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("EvSefDBConnection");
    }
```

and edit connection string and add this :

```
TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

It works